# Is it possible to use a field in a quote template - twice?

Tags: quote, quote-template

I am building some new Quote templates (Salesforce quote app)

Using the templates, is it possible to use the same field twice?

*The only solution I found was to use a simple formula field, that simply copies the value.

Comment: How is the page constructed? Were you using an `apex:repeat`? I've never encountered the need to use the same field twice, but am not certain why it would be an issue within a repeat. What behavior are you seeing when you do it without the formula?

Comment: I'm using the standard quote template pages. not visual pages.

Comment: Thank you. Would have to go back and look at it. I write a lot of custom ones using mostly standard html with repeats. I'd expect different behavior with a template comprised of VisualForce. Have you tried using the unmanaged package version of [Simple Quotes](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000017lEqEAIan) and Invoices?

Comment: Here's the correct link: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001TLtcEAG